# f-string with curly brace and function

Tags: python, f-string, one-liner

I searched for existing answers.  I found answers for printing curly braces, but they do not include executing a function inside the f-string as well.  The one marked as duplicate did not solve my problem.

Part of the string that I'm trying to print is resolved from a function.  The static part of my string includes curly braces.  I can perform the function using the old style, but I was hoping to do so with the new f-string.  The final string should look like this:

```
test{aloha}
```

Old style works:

```python
>>> print('test{%s}'%(aloha()))
'test{aloha}'
```

f-string - as expected, the curly braces are not printed:

```python
>>> print(f"test{(aloha())}")
'testaloha'
```

f-string with double curly - function is not executed:

```python
>>> print(f"test{{(aloha())}}")
"test{(xor('label'.encode(), 13).decode())}"
```

f-string escaping curly braces - syntax error:

```python
>>> print(f"test\{{(aloha())}\}")
"SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed"
```

f-string only escaping opening curly brace - no execution:

```python
>>> print(f"test\{{(aloha())}}")
"test\{(xor('label'.encode(), 13).decode())}"
```

Am I just reaching too far?

Edit: shortened the original executed function to "aloha()", but people already responded with working answers while I was editing. Their answers are correct.

Comment: I know that one liners like what I'm trying to accomplish can reduce readability, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this for the sake of learning.  Happy holidays!

Comment: The question was closed and marked as a duplicate, but I do not think that it is a duplicate. I saw the question that was linked before I posted mine, but it did not help me since I have an additional part to my question that is relevant. I showed the results of the answer used from that linked question in my own question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a triple curly. Each double curly makes for a single escaped curly braces:

```
>>> f"{{{1}}}"
'{1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```py
f"test{{{(xor('label'.encode(), 13).decode())}}}"
```